# Função que retorna se um podemos ir ao banco com true/false?

Tags: javascript, string, condição, booleano

**EXERCICIO:**  Defina a função possoIrAoBanco que, receba dois parâmetros, o primeiro é diaDaSemana (string) e o segundo horaAtual(numero), a função deve retornar true, apenas se o banco estiver aberto. Lembre-se que você pode fazer o que é necessário usando o return **sem fazer uso de if/else.**

**FIZ O SEGUINTE CODIGO:**

```
function possoIrAoBanco( diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
 var horaFuncionamentoBanco = (9, 10,11,12,13,14,15);
  var diasFuncionamentoBanco = ('segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira','quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira');
 return horaAtual === horaFuncionamentoBanco &&diaDaSemana=== diasFuncionamentoBanco;
}
```

**POREM:** Antes estava aparecendo o erro da solução ir contra string, mas usei a dica do colega Sergio em outra questão que eu tive duvida e pensei que iria resolver. Mas agora quando coloco o seguinte teste no console
possoIrAoBanco('sexta-feira', 10) ele retorna FALSE mesmo a data sendo sexta-feira e o horario sendo 10.
Alguém saberia explicar o que está causando esse erro?

Comment: function possoIrAoBranco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) { var diasFechados = ('Sábado', 'Domingo'); return diaDaSemana !== diasFechados && horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15; } Acredito que esse teste seja da Digital House. Caso seja, veja que ele não vai aceitar o código com var diasFechados = ('sábado', 'domingo'); mas somente com **('Sábado', 'Domingo')**. Não sei se isso foi algo previsto, mas todos os outros dias de trabalho são aceitos com letras minúsculas mas o final de semana não. Acredito que seja um erro, mas me deixou um bom tempo achando que a lógica da função estava errada.

Comment: function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
return horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15 && diaDaSemana != "Sábado" && diaDaSemana != "Domingo"
} O meu ficou assim e consegui passar... o problema é o acento do Sábado e o Domingo com letra maíuscula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, eu fiz assim e achei mais simples:

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual){

  var naoPode = ('sábado' || 'domingo');

  return diaDaSemana != naoPode && horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A resolução ficou assim:

```
function possoIrAoBanco( diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
var diasFuncionamentoBanco = ('segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira','quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira');
 return 9 <=horaAtual<=15&&diaDaSemana=== diasFuncionamentoBanco;
}
```

No caso, como o horário do banco é um número não teria a necessidade de atribuir a uma variável como estava fazendo com os diaDaSemana que é atribuída a uma string.

Comment: Pra mim isso sempre vai retornar false...??? isso não é uma funcao in_array... são strings, quando vc verifica o tipo, exemplo: `typeof ('segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira','quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira')` só retorna uma 'string', então seu === só vai verificar se é do tipo string... e se é igual a estrutura inteira o seu diaDaSemana... que será um valor que seria de um array, então não faz sentido nenhum isso. A menos que vc mude esse parênteses para colchetes. `[ ]`, e percorra em cada posição... [+]

Comment: [+] ou retorne se o tipo for diferente de -1, `return (diasFuncionamentoBanco.indexOf(diaDaSemana) !== -1)`

Answer (score 2):

No javascript o tipo string só pode armazenar um valor e não uma "lista" de valores como você está fazendo.

Você disse que seu exemplo funcionou testando com o parâmetro sexta-feira é porque na "lista" que você criou sexta-feira é o ultimo valor informado no qual será associado a string **diasFuncionamentoBanco** e os outros valores serão descartados, se você testar qualquer outro parâmetro diferente de sexta-feira irá falhar.

Para resolver isso ao invés de definir **diasFuncionamentoBanco** como **string** seria melhor como **array** e testar se o valor passado como argumento está contido dentro do array usando o método **arrayOf(item)**.

**arrayOf** retorna a posição do item no array ou -1 se o item não estiver contido no array, então só precisamos verificar se o **diaDaSemana** é diferente de -1.

```js
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
  const diasFuncionamentoBanco = ['segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira'];

  const diaDeFuncionamento = diasFuncionamentoBanco.indexOf(diaDaSemana) !== -1;

  const horarioDeFuncionamento = horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15;

  return diaDeFuncionamento && horarioDeFuncionamento;
}

console.log(`domingo as 8: ${possoIrAoBanco('domingo', 8)}`);
console.log(`segunda as 9: ${possoIrAoBanco('segunda-feira', 9)}`);
console.log(`terça as 10: ${possoIrAoBanco('terça-feira', 10)}`);
console.log(`quarta as 20: ${possoIrAoBanco('quarta-feira', 20)}`);
console.log(`quinta as 12: ${possoIrAoBanco('quinta-feira', 12)}`);
console.log(`sexta as 15: ${possoIrAoBanco('sexta-feira', 15)}`);
console.log(`sabado as 14: ${possoIrAoBanco('sabado', 14)}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta funcionou para mim...

```
var segunda = "segunda-feira";
var terca = "terca-feira";
var quarta = "quarta-feira";
var quinta = "quinta-feira";
var sexta = "sexta-feira";
var sabado = "sábado";
var domingo = "domingo";
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
  return diaDaSemana != sabado && diaDaSemana != domingo && horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim:

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
  var dia = ('segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira');
  return diaDaSemana === dia && horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15;
}

console.log(possoIrAoBanco('sabado', 11));
```

Answer (score -1):

Tiver que declarar todos os dias da semana para funcionar.

```
function possoIrAoBanco (diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
  var segunda = "segunda-feira";
var terca = "terca-feira";
var quarta = "quarta-feira";
var quinta = "quinta-feira";
var sexta = "sexta-feira";
var sabado = "sábado";
var domingo = "domingo";

  return diaDaSemana != sabado
      && diaDaSemana != domingo 
      && horaAtual >= 9 
      && horaAtual <= 15;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function possoIrAoBanco (diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {

var segunda= 'Segunda';
var terca = 'Terça';
var quarta = 'Quarta';
var quinta = 'Quinta';
var sexta = 'Sexta';
var sabado = 'Sábado';
var domingo =  'Domingo';

return (diaDaSemana !== sabado) &&( diaDaSemana !== domingo) && (horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15) ;
} 


possoIrAoBanco( 'Segunda', 10);
possoIrAoBanco('Terça', 18) ;
possoIrAoBanco('Sábado', 11);
possoIrAoBanco('Domingo',13) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Olá, depois de 1 hora de tentativas essa solução deu super certo.

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
    return (!(diaDaSemana == "Sábado" || diaDaSemana == "Domingo") && (horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15));
}
```

Tudo que você tem que fazer é colocar a lógica dentro de uma chave mãe e negar tudo, dizendo que o que for verdadeiro no fim é falso =)

Answer (score -2):

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana,horaAtual) {

var diasFuncionamentoBanco = ('segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira','quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira');

  var sabado = "sábado"

  var domingo = "domingo"

  return (horaAtual > 0  && horaAtual <= 15)  && (diaDaSemana != sabado && diaDaSemana != domingo ) || diaDaSemana ==  diasFuncionamentoBanco;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
    return diaDaSemana != "Sábado" && diaDaSemana != "Domingo" && horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <=15;
}
```

Eu fiz o mesmo exercício no Digital House, e a única resposta que ele aceitou como certa foi essa acima.