# Exercicio Posso ir ao banco?

Tags: javascript

Eu com um problema em um exercício de um curso online que estou fazendo, já tentei de todas as formas que eu consegui chegar porem ele não aceita. Não sei onde estou errando. O Exercicio está abaixo, junto com o meu codigo.

Enunciado:

> Agora vamos criar uma função que nos diga se o banco está fechado?
>
> Primeiro de tudo precisamos saber que um banco está fechado quando é
>   fim de semana (sábado ou domingo) e não está no horário bancário (9 às
>   15hs).
>
> Defina a função possoIrAoBanco que, receba dois parâmetros, o primeiro
>   é diaDaSemana (string) e o segundo horaAtual(numero), a função deve
>   retornar true, apenas se o banco estiver aberto.
>
> Exemplo:
>
> ```
> possoIrAoBanco("segunda-feira", 10); // true, é um dia da semana e está no horário bancário, 10hs
> possoIrAoBanco("terça-feira", 18); // false, é dia da semana e NÃO está no horário bancário, 18hs
> possoIrAoBanco("Sábado", 11); // false, é fim de semana
> ```
>
> Lembre-se que você pode fazer o que é necessário usando o `return` sem fazer uso de `if`/`else`.

Erro que aparecem são este :

> A execução da função `possoIrAoBanco('Segunda', 10)` deve retornar `true` 
>   A execução da função `possoIrAoBanco('Terça', 18)` deve retornar `false`
>   A execução da função `possoIrAoBanco('Sábado', 11)` deve retornar `false` 
>   A execução da função `possoIrAoBanco('Domingo',13)` deve retornar `false`

O meu código está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Função que retorna se um podemos ir ao banco com true/false?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/406324/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-retorna-se-um-podemos-ir-ao-banco-com-true-false)

Answer (score 1):

> Ontem eu fiz esse mesmo código, espero que te ajude e seja bem vinda a plataforma.

```js
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual) {
  const diasFuncionamentoBanco = ['segunda-feira', 'terça-feira', 'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira'];

  const diaDeFuncionamento = diasFuncionamentoBanco.indexOf(diaDaSemana) !== -1;

  const horarioDeFuncionamento = horaAtual >= 9 && horaAtual <= 15;

  return diaDeFuncionamento && horarioDeFuncionamento;
}

console.log(`domingo as 8: ${possoIrAoBanco('domingo', 8)}`);
console.log(`segunda as 9: ${possoIrAoBanco('segunda-feira', 9)}`);
console.log(`terça as 10: ${possoIrAoBanco('terça-feira', 10)}`);
console.log(`quarta as 20: ${possoIrAoBanco('quarta-feira', 20)}`);
console.log(`quinta as 12: ${possoIrAoBanco('quinta-feira', 12)}`);
console.log(`sexta as 15: ${possoIrAoBanco('sexta-feira', 15)}`);
console.log(`sabado as 14: ${possoIrAoBanco('sabado', 14)}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Natalia, veja se o código abaixo funciona:

```js
function possoIrAoBanco(diaDaSemana, horaAtual){
 return diaDaSemana == 6 || horaAtual == 10; 

}
```